# Force third party to delete ssn from database

Tags: privacy, california, identity-theft

I erroneously gave my ssn to a recruiter working for a tech recruitment company. They asked for it because they needed it to post me for a bank job. At least that's what they claimed.

Long story short, I do not want them to possessing my ssn. Is there a way I can get them to delete my number?? And beyond that prove they did. Is there any legal action in case they lied?

Resources around controlling who has your ssn would be appreciated.

PS. This is all in California.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave information that is true to someone voluntarily.

There is no legal basis for you to have a right to tell them to delete that information. They don't appear to have misused this information so far, and you don't appear to have suffered any damages.

If your Social Security number is misused in the future, this company might be a suspect, although I strongly suspect that your fears are misplaced, and that it will not be misused.

Comment: The company may not misuse it, but if their security isn't quite up to par it's always possible that someone else could obtain a list of valid SSNs from that company without their permission, if the company keeps them on file.

Comment: @JAB would they be liable for negligence at that point?  Is there any legislation that is introducing controls over this? Of all the personal information out there control over our SSN is the most important.

Comment: @GregIven Honestly, the importance of the SSN is overrated and has to be distributed to lots of people anyway.

Comment: I find the fact that SSNs are used for so much to itself be an issue.

Comment: @JAB The SSN was invented to accurately link information reporting to tax returns, and to do that, everyone who gives you significant amounts of money needs to know your SSN.

Comment: Under the current system, yes, but a system where such numbers or tokens are produced on an as-needed basis and only associated with specific individuals and the business reporting the information/transaction for the associated token on the tax agency side would likely be more secure. Of course, I'm thinking of this from software authentication standpoint and I suppose it would be difficult to implement given human nature and how much tax work is still done on paper.

Comment: @JAB The solution is not more secure SSN analogs; the solution is more secure authentication of the identity of people who enter into financial transactions. For example, one could have a secure password protected server that the customer has to direct to send an authentication to someone seeking to set up a new credit account or bank deposit or brokerage account or seeking to reset a password would have to send to the firm setting it up or resetting the password.